# Can not upload video on facebook page via facebook graph api in python

Tags: python, facebook-graph-api, python-requests, http-post

```
PAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN ='...'
    location_of_video='Pokemon.mp4'
    payload = {
        'access_token':PAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN,
        'source':location_of_video
    }
    headers = {'content-type': 'multipart/form-data'}

    url = 'https://graph-video.facebook.com/v14.0/{}/videos'.format(pageId)
    r = requests.post(url, json=payload, headers=headers)
    print(r.text)
```

I tried using post request to post video on facebook page. I got error with accesstoken permission

```
{"error":{"message":"An access token is required to request this resource.","type":"OAuthException","code":104,"fbtrace_id":"ARidN0DcLJynUVOGLaIfQ-t"}}
```

[This is how I get the accesstoken](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wVJLU.png)

how can I fix it? Thanks you